# Why did Obé want people to kill for him?

Tags: mortel

In the TV series *[Mortel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortel)*, the god Obé seems to be looking for mortals to kill someone for him in order to return to his own realm, which is why he tries to pressure Sofiane, and later Victor, into committing murder.

Except, so far as I can tell, his face started to look decayed, presumably signifying his being trapped in the mortal world, directly *after* he claimed the life of Reda (if that is indeed what happened). In fact, this fits rather well with the fact that his condition worsens when he intervenes physically. Furthermore, he already had someone who was, seemingly, willing to kill as many people as Obé wanted in order to get what he desired, so it seems strange that he would focus on getting Victor and Sofiane to kill for him. That said, he *really* seemed to be insistent on them doing it.

So what is Obé's game? What does he *really* want to gain from having people killed for him? Why does he change whom he is working with?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there are a lot of mysteries unsolved, and I haven't found any official explanation for that plot point (or even that many fan theories, oddly enough), but my impression is that Obé is trapped in the mortal realm by one of his prior actions, which may or may not be related to Reda's death (if he did indeed die) and the the actions of the other killer. He is also shown to be somewhat incompetent, the least of his family, and prone to mistakes. My suspicion is that:

> He incorrectly set up the bargain with Hervé and as a result is being drained of his energy by every killing rather than empowered. His attempt to right things involves getting Sofiane and Victor properly ensnared in a bargain and to seal the deal by killing Hervé, eliminating both this drain on his energy and gaining the ability to gain new energy from their act. Traditionally, the [Loa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loa) have no power of their own, only acting as intermediaries for *Bondye*, so it would fit that he is sort of running off of batteries, with an additional drain from Hervé and that improperly executed agreement.

Of course, this is more or less speculatory, but I think it fits what facts we receive in the show.